# Laravel: multi-auth with common login page

Tags: laravel, authentication

Laravel version: 7.x

I need to develop an application where there are 2 main `roles` and multiple `sub-roles`, such as: `administrator` / `manager` , `office-admin`, etc. and `company` / `field-agent`, `front-desk`. Where `administrator` is the site owner and `company` is the `franchise`.

Tables:

```
users         ->        user_staff
|- id                   |- id
|- email                |- user_id
|- password             |- email
|- ...                  |- password
                        |- ...

companies     ->        employees
|- id                   |- id
|- email                |- company_id
|- password             |- email
|- ...                  |- password
                        |- ...
```

After login they all come to a common admin area (`http://www.sitename.com/admin/`) with their respective `role` limitations.

To manage this scenario I have created 4 different guards. `admin`, `staff`, `company` & `employee`.

Auth.php

```php
'guards' => [
    'admin' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'staff' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'staff',
    ],
    'company' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'company',
    ],
    'employee' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'employee',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\User::class,
    ],
    'staff' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\UserStaff::class,
    ],
    'company' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\Company::class,
    ],
    'employee' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\Employee::class,
    ],
],
```

---

Q: Can this be done via a common login page or do I have to create multiple login pages with urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Here is my final code:

*LoginController.php*

```php
public function login()
{
    # validating posted data
    $auth = $this->validator(request()->all())->validate();
    $success = false;

    # validating credentials
    foreach ([ 'admin', 'staff', 'company', 'employee' ] as $key => $guard)
    {
        if(\Auth::guard($guard)->attempt($auth, false))
        {
            $success = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    # redirecting with error(s)
    if($success == false)
        return redirect()
            ->route('admin.login')
            ->withInput()
            ->with('error', config('messages.auth.login.failed.message'));

    # redirecting to intended page
    return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
}
```

*Controller.php*

```php
public function __construct()
{
    /**
     * Middleware(s)
     */
    $this->middleware('auth:admin,staff,company,employee');

    ...
}
```